# Conditional Expectation Question from Grimmett & Stirzaker 1000 exercises in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent discrete random variables, let $z$ be a constant real number.

Why is $\Bbb E(X \mid  X + Y = z)$ not equal to $\Bbb E(X \mid X = z - Y)$? Is ${X+Y=z}$ not the same event as ${X=z-Y}$?

Comment: What's the definition of $E(X|Y)? Plug in your conditions.

Comment: I know the definition of E(X|B) for any event B. It is the sum over all x of xP(X = x | B). I think this means the only way E(X | X + Y = z) can be different from E(X |X = z - Y) is for the event {X+Y=z} to be different from the event {X=z-Y}. But I don't see why these events are different.

Comment: Why do you think they are different? Is this the whole question from the exercise?

Comment: It is not the whole question. The whole questions is, what is wrong with the following:

Let X and Y be random variables with mean μ

E(X | X + Y = z) = E(X | X = z − Y ) = E(z − Y ) = z − μ.

Comment: Maybe they are not different events... Maybe the problem is when the probability of one of the event is zero and the conditional probability becomes undefined.

Comment: The problem is not due to a conditioning by an event of probability zero, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The whole question is, what is wrong with the following: Let X and Y be (independent) random variables with mean μ, (then) E(X | X + Y = z) = E(X | X = z − Y) = E(z − Y) = z − μ.

The trouble is not with $E(X \mid X + Y = z) = E(X \mid X = z − Y )$, always true since, as you noted, $[X+Y=z]=[X=z-Y]$, but with your assertion that $E(X \mid X = z − Y ) = E(z − Y )$. Why would this identity be true, even with $X$ and $Y$ independent?

To get a grasp of the problem, consider the case when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli uniform on $\{0,1\}$ and $z=2$. Then $[X=z-Y]=[X=Y=1]$ hence $E(X \mid X = z − Y )=1\ne\frac32=E(z-Y)$.